# Does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {\sin(n+\frac{1}{n})}{\log\log n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {\sin(n+\frac{1}{n})}{\log\log n}$  converge?

**My attempts** :

$\sin(x+y) = \sin x\cos y + \cos x \sin y$

now $\sin(n +\frac{1}{n}) = \sin n \cos \frac{1}{n} + \cos n\sin\frac{1}{n}$

now $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {\sin n \cos 1/n }{\log\log n} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac {\cos n \sin 1/n}{\log\log n}}$

After that I can not able to proceed further.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {\sin( n + 1/n) }{\log\log n}&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {\sin n \cos 1/n }{\log\log n} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac {\cos n \sin 1/n}{\log\log n}}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sin n\,\frac {1 }{\log\log n} +\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {(\sin n)(\cos 1/n-1) }{\log\log n}+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\cos n\,\frac { \sin 1/n}{\log\log n}}.
\end{align}
By Dirichlet's test, the first and last series converge. The second one is absolutely convergent, since $\cos 1/n-1\sim -1/(2n^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) in order to show that it converges.

Comment: How would you apply Dirichlet's test to the original series?

Comment: You are right. Dirichlet's test doesn't apply here, I tried using the integral test, Wolfram Mathematica says that the integral does not converges, but I can't find any proof.